# How to do arithmetic modulo 2^32 in PHP

Tags: php

PHP automatically converts integers that would overflow to floats, is there a way to stop it from doing that and ensure proper wrapping behaviour? Throwing in a `& 0xFFFFFFFF` doesn't help, it happens too late, after the low bits have already been rounded away in the float.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent the float conversion, but you could detect if an overflow occurred by seeing if the result is > [PHP_INT_MAX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max) (or simply checking if the result [is_float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)!)

You could perhaps use the [GMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php) extension which allows arbitrary length integers, and handle the overflowing yourself when you exceed 2<sup>32</sup>